# Azpen A1040 root method

Tags: rooting, 4.4-kitkat, tablet

I have an Azpen A1040 10" tablet and I have tried multiple root methods, nothing seems to work for this kitkat device.  I see some android enthusiasts successfully rooted this device.  Please let me know what method you used?  Thanks!

Comment: related: [How do i root my Android device?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/1184/how-do-i-root-my-android-device) and the [rooting tag-wiki](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/rooting/info). Start with looking at those places, as they not only contain device specific (I don't see your device), but also "common" methods that can be used to root many different devices.

Comment: Have you tried using TowelRoot? It is compatible with many devices.

Answer (score -1):

The A1040 works using [Kingoapp Root](http://www.kingoapp.com/). As pointed out in [How do I root my Android device?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/1184/16575) (our "rooting index"):

> Pratically roots most androids in 1-click and supports kitkat. Even unlocks some bootloaders. Windows PC required.

Comment: Could you give more details, like what is Kingoapp Root, where to get it, how to use it?